# Update multilevel records using - wcf client data services / odata

Tags: c#, wcf-data-services, odata

I am looking for service example where multilevel update is done by using wcf client data service.

For example, I have Order 101 inside this class I have list of Order Details 301,302,303.

I want to send complete Order with all order details to server for update operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can send them from the client as a batch payload in a single changeset. The semantics of operation within a changeset are either all succeed or none.

Currently OData protocol does not have support for nested entities in update operation. You can insert them together in an insert operation, but for update, one must use Batch mode if they want bunch of operations to succeed atomically.

Hope this helps.

Thanks
Pratik

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you have any microsoft or odata official link which has mention this ?

Comment: can you please provide the link